# Expecting int return value

Tags: xml, f#

I have following code snippet, which evaluates an XML file:

```ml
open System
open System.IO
open System.Xml.Linq
open FSharp.Data
open System.Net

type InputXml = XmlProvider<"C:\Temp\sample.xml">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let input = InputXml.Load("C:\Temp\sample.xml")

    for customer in input.GetCustomers() do
    for order in customer.GetOrders() do
    for line in order.GetOrderLines() do
        printfn "Customer: %s, Order: %s, Item: %s, Quantity: %d"
                customer.Name order.Number line.Item line.Quantity

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The compiler shows the following error:

```ml
Error   1   This expression was expected to have type
    int    
but here has type
    unit    D:\f#\samples\Program.fs    16  5   samples
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# is whitespace delimited.  That means that this:

```ml
for customer in input.GetCustomers() do
for order in customer.GetOrders() do
for line in order.GetOrderLines() do
```

needs to be more like this:

```ml
for customer in input.GetCustomers() do
  for order in customer.GetOrders() do
    for line in order.GetOrderLines() do
```

otherwise the scope of the body of the first `for` continues until the end of the current level of indentation (which includes the `0`).  You could use the old style of syntax to fix this by doing something like this:

```ml
for customer in input.GetCustomers() do
for order in customer.GetOrders() do
for line in order.GetOrderLines() do

...

done
done
done
0
```

but this is highly non-idiomatic at this point.